# How to create a function which loops through column index numbers in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, multiple-columns

Consider the following data frame (df):

```
"id"   "a1"   "b1"   "c1"   "not_relevant"   "p_a1"   "p_b1"   "p_c1"
 a      2      6      0           x             2        19       12
 a      4      2      7           x           3.5         7       11
 b      1      9      4           x             7       1.5        4
 b      7      5      11          x             8        12        5
```

I would like to create a new column which shows the sum of the product between two corresponding columns. To write less code I address the columns by their index number. Unfortunately I have no experience in writing functions, so I ended up doing this manually, which is extremely tedious and not very elegant.

Here a reproducible example of the data frame and what I have tried so far:

```
id <- c("a","a","b","b")
df <- data.frame(id)
df$a1 <- as.numeric((c(2,4,1,7)))
df$b1 <- as.numeric((c(6,2,9,5)))
df$c1 <- as.numeric((c(0,7,4,11)))
df$not_relevant <- c("x","x","x","x")
df$p_a1 <- as.numeric((c(2,3.5,7,8)))
df$p_b1 <- as.numeric((c(19,7,1.5,12)))
df$p_c1 <- as.numeric((c(12,11,4,5)))

require(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(total = .[[2]]*.[[6]] + .[[3]] *.[[7]]+ .[[4]] *.[[8]])
```

This leads to the desired result, but as I mentioned is not very efficient:

```
"id"   "a1"   "b1"   "c1"   "not_relevant"   "p_a1"   "p_b1"   "p_c1"   "total"
 a      2      6      0           x             2        19       12     118.0
 a      4      2      7           x           3.5         7       11     105.0
 b      1      9      4           x             7       1.5        4      36.5
 b      7      5      11          x             8        12        5     171.0
```

The real data I am working with has much more columns, so I would be glad if someone could show me a way to pack this operation into a function which loops through the column index numbers and matches the correct columns to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Column indices are not a good way to do this. (Not a good way in general...)

Here's a simple `dplyr` method that assumes the columns are in the correct corresponding order (that is, it will give the wrong result if the `"x1", "x2", "x3"` is in a different order than `"p_x3", "p_x2", "p_x1"`). You may also need to refine the selection criteria for your real data:

```
df$total = rowSums(select(df, starts_with("x")) * select(df, starts_with("p_")))
df
#   id x1 x2 x3 not_relevant p_x1 p_x2 p_x3 total
# 1  a  2  6  0            x  2.0 19.0   12 118.0
# 2  a  4  2  7            x  3.5  7.0   11 105.0
# 3  b  1  9  4            x  7.0  1.5    4  36.5
# 4  b  7  5 11            x  8.0 12.0    5 171.0
```

The other good option would be to convert your data to a long format, where you have a single `x` column and a single `p` column, with an "index" column indicating the 1, 2, 3. Then the operation could be done by group, finally moving back to a wide format.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately the selection criteria for my real data does not match with the example I provided. I will edit the example accordingly. The column names should be `"a1" "b1" "c1"`. However, the order of the columns  is correct.

Comment: Yeah, you can see the `?select_helpers` help page for lots of examples of what can be done there. For `"a1", "b1", "c1"`, you might use `matches("^[a-z]1$")`, for "any letter followed by a 1". If the number isn't always a 1, then perhaps `matches("^[a-z][0-9]$")` for "any letter followed by any number".

Comment: Thank you again for your help. The solution is probably to add a prefix or suffix to the corresponding columns. This way, I can artificially create a selection criterium. For example like this:`"pre_a1" "pre_b1" "pre_c1" `

Comment: Yeah, you just need *some* way to programmatically identify the column names.